# Alternate output format of Snowflake CLI for wide output with many columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to alternate output format of snowsql for wide output with many columns. However I don't see such option.
For example in Postgres cli it is `\x on`. In MySQL it is `\G` at the end of the query.
Is it also possible with snowflake cli

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options for SnowSQL in the connection parameters section of the documentation.  You may want to play around with the `output_format` options to see if any of those are better suited for you.  I don't know how the options relate to the other CLIs that you mention, though.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#output-format

Answer (score 0):

For the next person who finds this post:

```
!set output_format=expanded;
```

is what you want.